# Python load .pem public key

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have an ERCA pem file and need to load it in as a public key, which is then used to decrypt some data.

```
------------ BEGIN ERCA PK ---------------
/UVDIAD//wHpgHY6REqVJQqVh4LR1UrPwyPSXzlGuBbpL8+dMrQqJhPRo2O05DUyoCZoYynI
lmPMwAH3J4IGtqtlrShxhIpoD2pX2P2h14LJtYEpA+pbZuKpvh2FvdD9rnakYIjXGmF2sfap
hBkQBCTcVtCEaqPIQ5DTUXoPEZLe3/dAkkzbpwAAAAAAAQAB
------------ END ERCA PK ---------------
```

Now I basically do this

```
    file = open(".\dddfiles\EC_PK\EC_PK.pem", 'rb')
    b = file.read()
    file.close()
    rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_der(b)
```

But it gives me the errors:

```
File "C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\QanALL_CMD_Tools\src\ddd_parser.py", line 97, in <module>
    _7601_.validate()
  File "C:\Users\Oscar\Documents\QanALL_CMD_Tools\src\parser7601.py", line 89, in validate
    rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_der(b)
  File "C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rsa\key.py", line 375, in load_pkcs1_openssl_der
    (keyinfo, _) = decoder.decode(keyfile, asn1Spec=OpenSSLPubKey())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1618, in __call__
    raise error.PyAsn1Error(
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: <TagSet object, tags 0:32:13> not in asn1Spec: <OpenSSLPubKey schema object, tagSet=<TagSet object, tags 0:32:16>, subtypeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>, componentType=<NamedTypes object, types <NamedType object, type header=<PubKeyHeader schema object, tagSet=<TagSet object, tags 0:32:16>, subtypeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>, componentType=<NamedTypes object, types <NamedType object, type oid=<ObjectIdentifier schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:6>>>, <NamedType object, type parameters=<Null schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:5>, subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object, consts <SingleValueConstraint object, consts b''>>, encoding iso-8859-1>>>, sizeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>>>, <NamedType object, type key=<OctetString schema object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:3>, encoding iso-8859-1>>>, sizeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>>
```

For the live of me, I tried a lot, can't get it to work, does anyone have any idea? I also have a BIN and txt file. Tried both, no difference.

To give some context: i'm trying to write code to validate signatures from Tachograph files. Each chapter has certificates which are used to create a signature of the data. If i understand the documentation correct, I need to unwrap the certificate of the chapter using the European public key, after which I have a new public key from the manufacturer which I can then use to verify the signature of the whole chapter. But I could be wrong about this all, as the documentation seems to be written by Albert Einstein and I'm far from his intellect, or any intellect for that matter.

Comment: Although it is certainly possible to create a better supported PEM file out of the "ERCA PK" file, you'd need to know the structure of the data within the base64. This seems to be a proprietary structure, so you're fully in your right to ask for the specifications if you ask me. The text file could be interesting so you might want to post that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a description of the format of an ERCA public key [here](https://dtc.jrc.ec.europa.eu/erca_of_doc/SPI04178.pdf) (from [here](https://dtc.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dtc_erca_official_documentation_dt.php.html)), chapter 4.3.1: The Base64 decoded data starts with the header 0xFD45432000FFFF01 followed by the 128 bytes modulus (n). The last 8 bytes contain the public exponent (e). Both in big endian order.

The import with the Python-RSA library (which you seem to use) is then possible as follows:

```py
import rsa
import base64

publicErca = b'''------------ BEGIN ERCA PK ---------------
/UVDIAD//wHpgHY6REqVJQqVh4LR1UrPwyPSXzlGuBbpL8+dMrQqJhPRo2O05DUyoCZoYynI
lmPMwAH3J4IGtqtlrShxhIpoD2pX2P2h14LJtYEpA+pbZuKpvh2FvdD9rnakYIjXGmF2sfap
hBkQBCTcVtCEaqPIQ5DTUXoPEZLe3/dAkkzbpwAAAAAAAQAB
------------ END ERCA PK ---------------'''

publicErcaBytes = base64.b64decode(publicErca.replace(b'------------ BEGIN ERCA PK ---------------', b'').replace(b'------------ END ERCA PK ---------------', b'').replace(b'\n', b''))

# Extract n, e
n = int.from_bytes(publicErcaBytes[8:8+128], 'big')
e = int.from_bytes(publicErcaBytes[8+128:], 'big')

# Import key
pubKey = rsa.PublicKey(**{'e': e, 'n': n})

# Do what you want to do, e.g. export as PEM encoded key in PKCS#1 format
print(pubKey.save_pkcs1().decode())
```

Note that the more modern Python libraries can also reconstruct a public key from n and e (e.g. PyCryptodome via [`RSA.construct()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html#Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.construct) or pyca/cryptography via [`rsa.RSAPublicNumbers()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicNumbers)).

Answer (score 0):

It's pem key, you can't just directly read it as text file
here try this and don't forget to install necessary packages.

```py
file = ".\dddfiles\EC_PK\EC_PK.pem"

rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_der(file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it doesn't work. it says:

File "C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1351, in __call__
    tagClass = integerTag & 0xC0
               ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Sorry, but "it's a PEM file" doesn't cut it as the type "ERCA PK" is unknown to most if not all libraries. Tachograph keys have a certain size, and I'm not entirely sure anymore what to expect. For certain the public exponent is at the end using 8 byte big endian encoding.